# jQuery command fails to create table when placed after select element

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery and built this code that I modified to make it work right away in fiddle etc.

When the select changes, it is supposed to create a table but it does not do anything. However, if I place the `<div id="myTableId">` element on top of the select `<select id="mySelect" />` it works. Any idea why?

```js
var service_data = [{
  "role": "paul",
  "display_name": "Paul",
  "content": [{
    "name": "AAA",
    "link": "alink"
  }, {
    "name": "BBB",
    "link": "blink"
  }]
}, {
  "role": "sally",
  "display_name": "Sally",
  "content": [{
    "name": "CCC",
    "link": "clink"
  }]
}];

$(document).ready(function() {
  //replaced service with dummy service
  $.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos", function(data, status) {

    var _select = $('#mySelect');

    $.each(service_data, function(val, text) {
      _select.append(
        `<option value="${val}">${text.display_name}</option>`
      );
    });
  });

  $("#mySelect").change(function() {
    let selected_index = $("#mySelect")[0].selectedIndex;
    var container = $('#myTableId');
    var table = $('<table>');

    $.each(service_data[selected_index].content, function(val, blob) {
      var tr = $('<tr>');
      tr.append('<td>' + blob.name + '</td>');
      tr.append('<td>' + blob.link + '</td>');
      table.append(tr);
    });

    container.append(table);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="mySelect" />
<br>
<div id="myTableId" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divs and selects aren't self-closing elements. They probably don't exist with respect to jQuery except where the browser attempts to close them for you. Fix that and it works.

```js
var service_data = [{
  "role": "paul",
  "display_name": "Paul",
  "content": [{
    "name": "AAA",
    "link": "alink"
  }, {
    "name": "BBB",
    "link": "blink"
  }]
}, {
  "role": "sally",
  "display_name": "Sally",
  "content": [{
    "name": "CCC",
    "link": "clink"
  }]
}];

$(document).ready(function() {
  //replaced service with dummy service
  $.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos", function(data, status) {

    var _select = $('#mySelect');

    $.each(service_data, function(val, text) {
      _select.append(
        `<option value="${val}">${text.display_name}</option>`
      );
    });
  });

  $("#mySelect").change(function() {
    let selected_index = $("#mySelect")[0].selectedIndex;
    var container = $('#myTableId');
    var table = $('<table>');

    $.each(service_data[selected_index].content, function(val, blob) {
      var tr = $('<tr>');
      tr.append('<td>' + blob.name + '</td>');
      tr.append('<td>' + blob.link + '</td>');
      table.append(tr);
    });

    container.append(table);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id="mySelect"></select>
<br>
<div id="myTableId"></div>
```